# jQuery: Setting Select Option Dynamically

Tags: jquery, select

```
child.attr('selectedIndex', 1);
```

Doesn't seem to work in my case.

I have two cascading dropdown lists, a parent and a child.  To start, they both contain the same values.  When a user selects an item from the parent select box, it is removed as a choice in the child select.

Sometimes, the parent select box has only 3 items, the default and 2 values.  When a user selects a parent value in this case, the only possible choice in the child select is the one remaining non-default value.

So, when the parent has only two values, I'd like to automatically select the non-default value that is left in the child box when a user selects something parent select.

The HTML I start with might be as follows:

```
<select name="from" class="from">
<option value="" selected="selected" class="default">Select a value</option>
<option value="na">One</option>
<option value="ja">Two</option>
</select>
<select name="to" class="to">
<option value="" selected="selected" class="default">Select a value</option>
<option value="na">One</option>
<option value="ja">Two</option>
</select>
```

Then if the user selects "One" in the parent, the child select should automatically have "Two" selected.

Here is my jQuery I use to remove a value from the child when a value in the parent is selected:

```
    (function ($) {
        function cascadeSelect(parent, child) {
            var childOptions = child.find('option:not(.default)');
            child.data('options', childOptions);
            parent.change(function () {
                childOptions.remove();
                child.append(child.data('options').filter('.' + this.value))
                    .change();
                if (child.data('options').length == 2) {
                    [select the last option here]
                }

            })

            if (parent.val()) {
                childOptions.not('.default, .' + parent.val()).remove();
            }

        }


        $(function () {
            cascadeForm = $('.askform');
            pulldown_from = cascadeForm.find('.from');
            pulldown_to = cascadeForm.find('.to');

            cascadeSelect(pulldown_from, pulldown_to);
        });
```

I've added the line that checks if there are only two options in the child select:

```
                if (child.data('options').length == 2) {
                    [select the non-default child option here]
                }
```

But I can't figure out how to select the non-default child option.  I thought I could do it by using the .selectedIndex:

```
child.attr('selectedIndex', 1);
```

But this seems to reference the original index values (the indexes as they were before I have removed the value selected in the parent).

So how can I automatically select the only non-default option in the child select when there are only two options to start with in the parent?

Comment: Your jQuery uses lots of class selectors, but there are no classes in your HTML. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the classes - updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a few issues.

In this line:

```
child.append(child.data('options').filter('.' + this.value))
             .change();
```

It look like you're trying to filter using a selector for the class (not the value).  You should hopefully be able to fix this by changing your selector so it filters based on the value of the option:

```
child.append(child.data('options').filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'))
             .change();
```

The easiest way to select a value in a dropdown is to just use `val()`.  In other words, the line you're after should read:

```
child.val(this.value);
```

I created a JS Fiddle if you want to see the whole thing working: http://jsfiddle.net/KkNHr/1/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work... but why not using attr?

```
child.get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

See for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/YqGU8/

```
$(".from").change(function() {
 var val = $(this).find(":selected").val();
 $(".to option[value='" + val + "']").remove();
 $(".to option:last").attr('selected','selected');
});​
```